# Displaying a subview on button click

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am developing an ios app in xamarin .How to display a subview(i have used xcode IB for creating a subview) when a button is clicked.Then when i click the same button, again  subview must be displayed.If button is pressed 3 times, 3 subviews must be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

In a very common way it will be something like that:

```cs
yourButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    var newView = new UIView();
    // do some stuff with your view here
    this.Add (newView);
};
```

Comment: I want a small subview with width 300 and height 50 to get displayed on button click.If i click button 4 times 4 subviews of width 300 and hieght 50 should get displaced.Will these subviews get displaed 1 after another?

Comment: pritam, each new view will get added, but they will be stacked on top of each other.  To place them in different places, create the new view with a RectangleF that will place them in different places, e.g.: `var newView = new UIView(new RectangleF(0, 50, 300, 50));`